# Crop thumbnail image in center with different width and height

Tags: php, image, position, crop

I am having this problem that my cropped image is not cropped in the center of the scaled image. I have now tried for some hours without success.
Any help on the calculation and position would be appreciated.

This is the part of the code that returns my values

```
    // image dimensions
    $obj->sw = $p_aImageInfo[0];
    $obj->sh = $p_aImageInfo[1];
    
    //thumbnail sizes
    $obj->tsw = 100;
    $obj->tsh = 200;
    

    $obj->yOff = 0;
    $obj->xOff = 0;
    if($obj->sw < $obj->sh) {
      $obj->scale = $obj->tsw / $obj->sw;
      $obj->yOff = $obj->sh/2 - $obj->tsw/$obj->scale/2; 
    } else {
      $obj->scale = $obj->tsh / $obj->sh;
      $obj->xOff = $obj->sw/2 - $obj->tsh/$obj->scale/2; 
    }
```

This the code that makes a new image

```
          // Create the resized image destination
      $croppedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($l_oCropInfo->tsw, $l_oCropInfo->tsh);
      imagealphablending($croppedImage, false);
      imagesavealpha($croppedImage,true);
      $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($croppedImage, 255, 255, 255, 127);
      imagefilledrectangle($croppedImage, 0, 0, $l_oCropInfo->tsw, $l_oCropInfo->tsh, $transparent);
      
      // Copy from image source, resize it, and paste to image destination
      imagecopyresampled($croppedImage, $im, 0, 0, $l_oCropInfo->xOff,
                                                   $l_oCropInfo->yOff,
                                                   $l_oCropInfo->tsw, 
                                                   $l_oCropInfo->tsh,
                                                   $l_oCropInfo->tsw / $l_oCropInfo->scale,
                                                   $l_oCropInfo->tsh / $l_oCropInfo->scale);
```

And the result of the image created and the one that needs to be created.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok small mistake now it works

Change

```
$obj->yOff = $obj->sh/2 - $obj->tsw/$obj->scale/2; 
$obj->xOff = $obj->sw/2 - $obj->tsh/$obj->scale/2;
```

to

```
$obj->yOff = $obj->sh/2 - $obj->tsh/$obj->scale/2;
$obj->xOff = ($obj->sw/2 - $obj->tsw/$obj->scale/2);
```